# If/else selected count from sql database

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

What I'm doing now is getting my SQL database table: IsAcross varchar(45) into my if/else statement. My IsAcross table only consist of YES and NO.

So now I want to take out only select YES statement from SQL Server, so therefore I have put the thingy in the whole list first. Then I use if/else statement to extract out the YES but how am I supposed to do that?

Example: I have a total of 7 items in a list, 4 yes 3 no. I want to take out the all the 4 yes only. Something like that:

```
ViewModels.WordSearchVM wsvm = new ViewModels.WordSearchVM();
wsvm.ActivityID = id;

var results = db.CrossPuzzles.Where(m => m.ActivityID == id)
                             .Select(m => m.IsAcross)
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .ToList();

if (results = "yes")
{
    else 
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling .AsEnumerable and .ToList? Also, results will never be equal to a string. It's an List of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you can forget your if statement and simply extend the .Where part:

```
.Where(m => m.ActivityID == id && m.results=="yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = db.CrossPuzzles.Where(m => m.ActivityID == id)
                             .Where(m => m.IsAcross)
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .ToList();

//OR

var results = db.CrossPuzzles.Where(m => m.ActivityID == id)
                             .Where(m => m.IsAcross == "YES")
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = db.CrossPuzzles
      .Where(m => m.ActivityID == id)
      .Select(m => m.IsAcross)
      .Where(x => x == "YES") // filter to "YES"
      .ToList();

if (results.Count > 0)
    // YES
else
    // NO
```

This what you're looking for?

Comment: The whole thing could be simplified to `if(db.CrossPuzzles.Any(m => m.ActivityID == id && m.IsAcross == "YES"))` then.